# Optimizing reading a `Vec` of custom types

Tags: rust

I am writing a protocol parsing library and want to optimize its speed while reading lists of data.

The library defines a read trait

```rust
trait Readable: Sized {
    fn read(reader: &mut impl std::io::Read) -> std::io::Result<Self>;
}
```

and implements all the primitives like so:

```rust
impl Readable for u8 {
    fn read(reader: &mut impl std::io::Read) -> std::io::Result<Self> {
        Ok(reader.read_u8()?)
    }
}
// same for i8, u16, i16 etc
```

The problem is with the `Vec` implementation, which is defined as

```rust
impl <T> Readable for Vec<T>
where T: Readable {
    fn read(reader: &mut impl std::io::Read) -> std::io::Result<Self> {
        let length = u16::read(reader)?;
        let mut items = Vec::with_capacity(length as usize);
        for _ in 0..length {
            items.push(T::read(reader)?);
        }
        Ok(items)
    }
}
```

It is common in the protocol to be reading large `Vec<u8>`, so the current implementation of reading `read_u8` on every item is not ideal. Using `read_exact` has almost 5x the performance at 100 bytes in my benchmarks, and the difference only gets larger as the size increases. (the reader is in-memory, not doing any IO)

The question is, how can I optimize this trait when reading `Vec<u8>` while keeping the functionality of being able to read generic lists of `Vec<T:Readable>`?

My current solutions are either:

1. Use [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html) on nightly, but I would rather stay on the stable channel.
2. add a `const IS_U8 : bool` to the `Readable` trait and call `read_exact` if `T::IS_u8` is true in the `Vec` impl, using `mem::transmutate` to return it as a `Vec<T>`. Adding a const for just this case is annoying and I'm not sure I can guarantee the safety of the implementation.

Is there a solution to this problem in stable rust?

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to force a sort of specialization in stable Rust. Here's something that compiles, though it's very awkward. I hope someone else has a less-awkward method. But this trick is to define a separate trait for the unspecialized types. For example:

```
trait XReadable: Sized {
    fn xread(reader: &mut impl std::io::Read) -> std::io::Result<Self>;
}

impl <T: XReadable> Readable for T {
    fn read(reader: &mut impl std::io::Read) -> std::io::Result<Self> {
        Self::xread(reader)
    }
}
```

So that now you can either implement `Readable` or `XReadable` for a type, and then use it as `Readable`. Now that you have that separation, you can define your unspecialized `Vec` behavior for `XReadable` only:

```
impl <T> XReadable for Vec<T>
where T: XReadable {
    fn xread(reader: &mut impl std::io::Read) -> std::io::Result<Self> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And define the specialized behavior explicitly with `Readable`:

```
impl Readable for Vec<u8> {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What are the rules for this? Is it guaranteed that the `Vec<u8>` impl will take precedence?

Comment: The trick is that there's no precedence, no ambiguity. Nothing conflicts with `Vec<u8>` because `u8` doesn't implement `XReadable`, only `Readable`. And the default `Vec` implementation is called `xread` instead of `read`.

Comment: @pidgeonhands `Vec<u8>` doesn't implement `XReadable` either.

Comment: It doesn't seem like `Vec<T: Readable>` works anymore. e.g. `Vec<u16>` wont read unless its been specifically implemented. This is a problem because `T` can be any arbitrary struct.

Comment: @pigeonhands `u16` should implement `XReadable`, and not `Readable` directly, if you want it to use the default `Vec` implementation.